# Incorporar un diccionario al diccionario de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una lista con un diccionario y quiero agregar a ese diccionario los datos de otro diccionario.

Esta es la lista con el diccionario original:

```
lista = [{'nombre' : 'Jose', 'edad' : 18}]
```

Este es el diccionario con los datos a agregar:

```
dict = {'cursos': ['Python','Flask','JavaScript']}
```

Quiero lograr el siguiente resultado:

```
resultado = [{'nombre' : 'Jose', 'edad' : 18, 'cursos': ['Python','Flask','JavaScript']}]
```

Creo que se debería hacer con la funcion *zip* pero no consigo el resultado que necesito.

Uso Python 3.6 Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: `lista[0]["cursos"] = dict["cursos"]` (y por cierto, no llames `dict` a una variable, es el nombre de un tipo en python)

Comment: @abulafia Excelente! muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al diccionario se le pueden agregar elementos de la forma:

```
dict[key] = value
```

Entonces:

```
>>> lista = [{'nombre' : 'Jose', 'edad' : 18}]
>>> d = {'cursos': ['Python','Flask','JavaScript']}
>>> lista[0]['cursos'] = d['cursos']
>>> lista
[{'nombre': 'Jose', 'edad': 18, 'cursos': ['Python', 'Flask', 'JavaScript']}]
```

Claro, se está colocando el nombre `'cursos'` manualmente como llave y así no funciona la programación, entonces debes tomar el índice y valor para insertarlo en el otro diccionario dinamicamente:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    lista[0][key] = value
```

### Plus

Como es de suponerse, hay otras *formas más pitónicas* de resolver esto:

Usando [dict.update()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)

```
>>> lista[0].update(d)
```

### Plus+

Python 3.9+ [d | other](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)

```
>>> lista[0] | d
{'nombre': 'Jose', 'edad': 18, 'cursos': ['Python', 'Flask', 'JavaScript']}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Cambiando `dict` por `d`

Si lo quieres en una nueva variable:

```
resultado = [{**lista[0], **d}]
```

Si no te imposta modificar `lista` (con permiso de @abulafia):

```
lista[0]["cursos"] = d["cursos"]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!